# Excel conditional formatting a record with two different columns as criteria

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a query table with about 280 resulting records/rows.  I want to highlight only the rows that satisfy two different conditions in two columns.  Here's what I've written so far but it doesn't work:

=AND(IF($O4="spec",1),IF($X4=7,1))
I want to highlight any row in which both column O of that row has spec in it, and column X has a 7 in it.  I've tried removing and adding the quotes on both the word spec and the 7, but it doesn't make a difference.

read somewhere that the conditionals don't work in a table and you need use named ranges; I've tried that but still didn't get the result I need.

Comment: Have tried simply `=AND($O4="spec",$X4=7)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to highlight any row in which both column O of that **row has spec in it**, and **column X has a 7 in it**.

These appear to be ambiguous statements and could mean that *spec* is only part of the text value in column O or that *spec* is the entire value.

This will work for either situation.

```
=AND(isnumber(search("spec", $O4), isnumber(search("7", $X4))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `IF`s. Try,

```
=AND($O4="spec",$X4=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula you have is more elaborate than necessary but the syntax is valid and the formula is capable of triggering a CF rule, whether or not inside a Table.

So it seems there may be something wrong with what you have neglected to mention, that is the "Applies to" range to which you are applying the formula. You may want the rows to run from Row4 to about Row284, but I am not guessing what columns to span.